# Не компилируется проект через cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Не компилируется проект через cx_Freeze в Python 3 на Linux

В проекте созданы два файла:

main.py

```
print('Hello, World!')
```

setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = "Win32GUI" if sys.platform == "win32" else None

setup(
    name="guifoo",
    version="0.1",
    description="My GUI application!",
    executables=[Executable("main.py", base=base)])
```

При запуске cx_Freeze командой `python setup.py build`

Выдает ошибку:

```
    raise OptionError(f"no base named {name!r} ({name_base!r})")
cx_Freeze.exception.OptionError: no base named 'console' ('console-cpython-39')
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Только вот такое нашёл, но не очень понятно, как чинить, хотя там есть варианты https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/2010

Comment: На каком дистрибутиве запускаете?

Comment: Alt Linux W 10.1

Comment: попробуйте установить модуль системным пакетом, а не через pip-инсталлятор.

Comment: Как вы предлагаете установить его системным пакетом?

Answer (score 0):

проблема вызвана обычно несоответствием двоичных библиотек операционной системы и поставляемыми с pip (напр, частая проблема с opencv и другими, требующими компиляции с/с++ кода)

сначала ищем название системного пакета

```
[apt|yum|dnf|zypper] search cx_freeze
```

напр., у меня их три в opensuse

```
S  | Name                | Summary                                                      | Type
---+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------
   | python39-cx_Freeze  | Scripts to create standalone executables from Python scripts | package
   | python310-cx_Freeze | Scripts to create standalone executables from Python scripts | package
i+ | python311-cx_Freeze | Scripts to create standalone executables from Python scripts | package
```

потом удаляем `pip3.10 uninstall cx_Freeze`

и далее по обстоятельствам т.к. названия пакетов могут быть разными, устанавливаем, напр.,

```
zypper install python310-cx_Freeze
```

Comment: благодаря вашему вопросу пробовал скомпилировать. отработала только nuitka (несколько часов), там был tkinter, matplotlib. вероятно лучше делать в виртуальном env, т.к. прошерстила все установленные питон-пакеты.